# Django Model Form not Saving || Instead writes to address bar

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I currently have a customer details form that I need to submit to the database.

However when I submit the form it does not save nor redirect as the code suggests. It instead **writes all the fields into the URL bar** of the page.

Models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class newCustomerClass(models.Model):
    customerName = models.CharField("Customer Name",max_length=50 , blank=True)
    addressStreetNo = models.CharField(max_length=50 , blank=True)
    addressStreet = models.CharField(max_length=50 , blank=True)
    addressSuburb = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True )
    addressCity = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True )
    addressPO = models.CharField(max_length=50 , blank=True)

    contact = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True )
    mail = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True )
    CellNo = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True )
```

Forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import newCustomerClass
from django.forms import ModelForm

class newCustomerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = newCustomerClass
        fields = 'customerName', 'addressStreetNo' ,'addressStreet', 'addressSuburb' ,'addressCity' , 'addressPO'  , 'contact' , 'mail' , 'CellNo'
```

Views.py:

```
def newCustomer(request):
    form = newCustomerForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = newCustomerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            print(form.errors)

    content = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'main/newCustomer.html' , content)
```

Templates.html:

```
{% extends "main/base.html"%}

{% block content %}
<br>
<div class="container" style="text-align: center">
    <form>
        {% csrf_token %}

          {{ form.non_field_errors }}

          {{ form.source.errors }}
          {{ form.source }}
        <h1 class="h1">New Customer</h1>

        <br>

        <h5>Customer Name {{ form.customerName }}</h5>

        <br>

        <h5>Street No {{ form.addressStreetNo }}</h5>
        <h5>Street Name {{ form.addressStreet }}</h5>
        <h5>Suburb {{ form.addressSuburb }}</h5>
        <h5>City {{ form.addressCity }}</h5>

        <br>

        <h5>Contact {{ form.contact }}</h5>
        <h5>E-Mail {{ form.mail }}</h5>
        <h5>Cell {{ form.CellNo }}</h5>

        <br>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Does anyone know what causes this , I have tried to it with some fields missing , and all fields full so I don't think the form is not valid either

Comment: By default forms perform `GET` requests. To `POST` you need to add `mathod="post"` attribute to the form element in template. You see submitted data in address bar because this is what happens when a form uses `GET`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you are not making any post request 
change this

```
<form>
        {% csrf_token %}

          {{ form.non_field_errors }}

          {{ form.source.errors }}
          {{ form.source }}
        <h1 class="h1">New Customer</h1>

        <br>

        <h5>Customer Name {{ form.customerName }}</h5>

        <br>

        <h5>Street No {{ form.addressStreetNo }}</h5>
        <h5>Street Name {{ form.addressStreet }}</h5>
        <h5>Suburb {{ form.addressSuburb }}</h5>
        <h5>City {{ form.addressCity }}</h5>

        <br>

        <h5>Contact {{ form.contact }}</h5>
        <h5>E-Mail {{ form.mail }}</h5>
        <h5>Cell {{ form.CellNo }}</h5>

        <br>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
    </form>
```

to

```
<form method='post' action='the-url-of-newCustomer'>
        {% csrf_token %}

          {{ form.non_field_errors }}

          {{ form.source.errors }}
          {{ form.source }}
        <h1 class="h1">New Customer</h1>

        <br>

        <h5>Customer Name {{ form.customerName }}</h5>

        <br>

        <h5>Street No {{ form.addressStreetNo }}</h5>
        <h5>Street Name {{ form.addressStreet }}</h5>
        <h5>Suburb {{ form.addressSuburb }}</h5>
        <h5>City {{ form.addressCity }}</h5>

        <br>

        <h5>Contact {{ form.contact }}</h5>
        <h5>E-Mail {{ form.mail }}</h5>
        <h5>Cell {{ form.CellNo }}</h5>

        <br>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
    </form>
```

you should replace the url `'the-url-of-newCustomer'` with your actual url and by default you can make it empty(so that means that the action will be the current url).